# Git error in Android Studio error saying Git is not installed

Tags: git, flutter, android-studio

Git is already installed in my Mac, but it still showing "Cannot identify version of git executable: no response"

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 1]

Comment: This answer works to me. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74336122/10649463

Comment: Try setting Path to Git executable: ```/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git```