# macOS 13 upgraded the xcode git commandline tools always try to find old SDK, even installed git it still claims I need to install

Tags: xcode, git, macos-ventura

xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk" cannot be located.

git: error: Failed to determine realpath of '/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk' (errno=No such file or directory)

this caused a dead lock, git can not found this path, and it can not be installed, then it ask to install, I installed, it can not foud this path, and it can not be installed.....

what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

> CAUTION: This is not a final fix but a quick one that worked for me.

Hi there,

I tried to delete CommandLine Tools and change the path to Xcode but nothing worked.

When you run `xcrun --show-sdk-path` it'll look for MacOSX12.3.sdk for some reason, the quickest solution now is to make a link and name it MacOSX12.3.sdk by running the following commands:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
ln -s ./MacOSX.sdk ./MacOSX12.3.sdk
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Running `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` at least enabled `xcrun --show-sdk-path`to find something instead of throwing an error.

But still it only finds the old `MacOSX12.3.sdk`